# How many rejected papers does it take to get an accepted paper?

Tags: paper-submission, rejection

Today I received my first rejected paper.

The committee of 2 people left some good points but at the end they didn't get the point of my theme. It took me 3 months to write this paper for the Requirements Engineering Conference in Lisbon, Portugal.

I talked to 2 PhD students and they said that this takes time and passion. They told me that the average of rejected papers/journals per capita is 7. Do you agree with this average?

Comment: Don't be too disheartened.  It's normal.  I've had papers accepted on the first go and I have one that took me five years with many revisions to publish. I would venture to say 7 would be 'normal' for a newbie trying to publish in reputable conferences, and over time, with experience and continued revision and guidance, this number would drop, possibly 2-3 rejections on average.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. That helps me get my frustration under control.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus, do you think 7 tries is expected if one has an advisor who provides some guidance on how to do the work, write the paper, and select the forum?  I grant that a "newbie" going it completely alone will hit major hurdles.

Comment: @FredDouglis like you said there are many factors.  Taking the 'advisor' factor into account, I would question his/her 'average rejection'.

Comment: If your papers are always accepted the first place you sent them, then you are aiming too low.

Comment: This is probably somewhat field dependent.  While I agree heartily with @GEdgar's comment [and he is also a mathematician], 7 seems like an unpleasantly large number to me.  The amount of time one would spend waiting for a math paper to be refereed 7 times is anywhere from 2 to 10 years: that seems like too long.  I can't think of a paper I've submitted more than four or five times, and having to submit that many times felt quite grueling.

Comment: Moreover, in order for a paper to get submitted 7 times and then accepted, that would seem to imply that there are 7 distinct tiers of conferences in the field.  That sounds like a lot, but even if it is the case, is it really wise to explore each of them in sequence?  Or do conference papers in some fields get refereed so quickly as to make this feasible?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark  In the field of Computer Science, it usually takes around 3 months to know the result.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I wouldn't say that implies there are 7 tiers.  In my mind, the decision on a paper is like a random variable, and it can make sense to sense to try at few different journals (nearly independent events) where you estimate you acceptance probability, say, at 50%.  (That said, I completely agree 7 seems really high, at least in math)

Answer (score 5):

This varies depending on a **huge** number of factors.  The venues you select to submit your work, the quality of the work, whether the work is described well or penalized because it is written badly, misses important related work, or many other factors.  And it no doubt depends on field as well.

I would however say that the idea that you submit 7 times for each time you get something published means you're setting your sights too high.  In Computer Science, for instance, probably most conferences have an acceptance ratio of 4:1 or 5:1, perhaps 6:1, at worst.  But then many others have much high acceptance ratios, so I would think the mean acceptance rate is 4:1 or 3:1.  In my own experience most papers have gotten in either the first time or the second.  One took 3, and another time I stopped trying to publish the work, but the average would be around 1.5-2 at most.

Whatever the ratio is in your field, by all means don't get too stressed over your first rejection.  It's part of the process!  And work with your advisor to find appropriate targets that are realistic.

Comment: @maxmin Without your advisor's help, it's virtually impossible to publish in good conferences.  I advise you to seek proper guidance before  re submission.  Otherwise, it's a waste of time.

Comment: Tks @lighthouse keeper ...

Answer (score 2):

I generally agree with Fred Douglis, and 7 resubmissions seems high.

However, it is important to note that the link between acceptance ratio of journals and the number of tries that are needed is not straightforward for many reasons. The review process is not random, the resubmissions are not independent trials, and you are supposed to improve your paper between submissions based on the reviews. So for example if someone keeps submitting to journals that are out of scope, is not skilled in writing, or refuses to consider reviewer feedback, they might need to submit as much as 7 times before getting a paper accepted.

Comment: While I generally agree to this answer, concerning the statement "The review process is not random" there is some [evidence](http://www.pgbovine.net/PhD-memoir/anderson-09.pdf) that the review process may actually include a non-negligible amount of randomness, especially for papers that are neither outstandingly good or bad.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper I agree - I did not mean that the process is not stochastic. I meant that there are factors such as the quality of writing, appropriateness of the selected journal/conference and the significance of the results that can affect the probability of acceptance.